# Test Cordova App on Android with external PC-based Database

Tags: javascript, php, android, cordova, phonegap

I have Programmed an Javascript jQuery based Website with connection to a php file.
I tested id on the Computer and everything worked bud if I start the Application on the Phone the App starts without the Information from the Database.
I use xampp for hosting on my computer.

How I have to change the Ajax request to get results?

```
 $.ajax({
              type:"POST",  //Request type
              url:"http://localhost/jQuery&PHPnew/LoginSch.N.php",
              data:{name:name, passwort:passwort},
              cache:false,
              success:function(data) {}
```

Comment: For the phone, try using the local computer's network ip address as opposed to `localhost`. Your phone and the local computer would ideally be on the same local network.

Comment: @GetSet Does this also work on an Emulated device?

Comment: `if I start the Application on the Phone` .. when you state this, it's not an actual phone?

Comment: @GetSet both I only want to know if it also runs on an emulated one but know I tested it on an phone and id didn't worked

Comment: I can only help you if its on an actual phone. I have no knowledge of your emulated setup. When it's an actual phone, what you can do is establish a wifi network, then connect both your server and your phone to this wifi network. Next change your ajax code for `url` to point to the `ip address` of your server. So `url` would be like: `url:"http://x.x.x.x/jQuery&PHPnew/LoginSch.N.php"`. If your server also needs access to the internet, connect your server to the internet via the ethernet port.

Comment: @GetSet I tried it this way, i setup an Hotspot with Phone2 then I connected the Mac and Phone1 with the HotSpot changed the localhost to the ip but it didn't work it gave no result like before

Comment: I'd suggest creating a test script that only returns `Hello World`. Use ajax to see if you can get the `Hello World` response. Debug based off this test script to see where your network issues reside. Hotspots can be tricky. The setup I mentioned without much trickyness is to have a wifi router inserted into your network. ... Also the ip in question would be the server's ip, not the hotspot's ip.

Comment: @GetSet I have to make a break I will write you later